# Why is &array != &array[0]?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, d

In C:

```
int a[10];
printf("%p\n", a);
printf("%p\n", &a[0]);
```

Yields:

```
0x7fff5606c600
0x7fff5606c600
```

Which is what I expect. Now, in D, I'm trying this (obviously no use case, just fooling around):

```
int[] slice = [...];
writeln(&slice);
writeln(&slice[0]);
```

Yields:

```
7FFF51600360
10E6E9FE0
```

Why the difference? Looks like a completely different memory segment. (Though it just occurred to me that perhaps arrays in D aren't just adjacently allocated ints?)

Comment: Because "array" itself is a pointer to the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in D an array is essentially a struct with a pointer and a length field and is treated as such

to get the address to the first element you can query the ptr field

Comment: This is true of dynamic arrays, arrays with a static length (e.g. int[10]) work like in C.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: You still should use `.ptr` to get a pointer to the first element. Also, it's worth noting that static arrays are passed by value for function arguments, i.e. the whole array is copied.

Answer (score 3):

Because "array" used by itself resolves to a pointer to the array, this allows you to treat pointer-to-type and array-of-type somewhat similarly when using structs.

```
int[] slice = [...];
writeln((cast(void*) slice);
writeln(&slice[0]);
```

should give you what you want.

Inherited from "C" http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

```
int[] slice = [...];
int* ptr = &slice[0];

writeln(cast(void*) slice);
writeln(&slice[0]);

// value access
writeln(slice[0]);
writeln(*ptr);
writeln(ptr[0]);
```

Comment: C-style casts are forbidden. Use `cast(void*) slice` instead as in the example: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/f708d945

Comment: I'm pretty sure casting a slice to void* will be banned at some point (or maybe I've misread that somewhere..).

Answer (score 3):

It is simple - dynamic D arrays are not the same as C arrays. Dynamic D arrays hold the length of the array, while C arrays do not. As such dynamic D arrays do not rely on a NULL to mark the end of the array. As Adam points out in his comment, static D arrays behave the same as C arrays.

```
import std.stdio;

int main() {
  // static array
  int[10] sarr;
  writeln(sarr.length);
  writeln(&sarr);
  writeln(&sarr[0]);

  // dynamic array
  int[] darr = [1, 2, 3];
  writeln(darr.length);
  writeln(&darr);
  writeln(&darr[0]);

  // These are all the same
  writeln(darr.ptr);
  writeln(cast(void*) darr);
  writeln(&darr[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

(DPaste link: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/f708d945)